# Filesystem check not completing after reboot after 20.04 upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, 20.04, fsck, disk-check

Yesterday I got a pop up on my Ubuntu installation running 19.10 saying that 20.04 is available. I figure I'd give the upgrade a try, hoping it wouldn't take too long. The upgrade completed, and my computer restarted, at which point a filesystem check seems to have started. I let it run overnight, and at this point it's been going for around 12 hours.

At some point I tried cancelling it because it said "Press ctrl+c to cancel all file system checks in progress" on the screen. However after unplugging my external monitor I just see a spinner, the Lenovo logo and a Ubuntu logo.

My question: do these checks usually take this long? is it safe to try and stop it? I'm dual booting with Windows 10 if that makes a difference.

Comment: How big is the partition that is being checked, and how much of it is in use? Anyway 12 hours is a lot.

Comment: It's fairly small, I think only 100-150GB. At most 50GB is in use I would expect.

Comment: Create a live medium, boot from it, and let the `fsck` run from there. Apparently there is really something wrong with your disk that needs to be corrected.

Comment: Is it safe to stop the filesystem check while it's running?

Comment: Yes. It is reading most of the time, and (probably) cannot be stopped while writing.

Comment: I was able to successfully turn off my computer while it was running and still have everything boot okay, so thank you! I'll give it a `fsck` sometime soon.

Comment: Having the exact same problem, I think there is a bug in 20.04 fschk